# How to tell if Python module is a namespace module

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, namespaces

In Python 3, modules can be namespace modules without an `__init__.py` (as per [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)) or as a regular module (i.e. '[modules] packages as they are implemented in Python 3.2 and earlier' - [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)) that have an `__init__.py` or are a single `.py` file.

How can you tell the difference between a namespace module and an 'ordinary' module?

(I am using Python 3.5.3)

e.g.
Namespace module named `mod` prints out as:

```
(Pdb) mod
<module 'mymodule' (namespace)>
```

and ordinary modules print out as:

```
(Pdb) mod
<module 'mymodule' from '/path/to/mymodule/__init__.py'>
```

Comment: BTW the way it printed depends on the interpreter

Comment: @abccd: What's unclear about it? Have you just not heard of [namespace packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)?

Comment: @user2357112 have you just not heard of the OP can edit the post within the first minute and not show up as a *edit*? And have you just not see that I deleted that comment after that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Namespace packages have a `__path__`, and either `__file__` set to `None` or no `__file__` attribute. (`__file__` is set to `None` on [Python 3.7 and later](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#other-cpython-implementation-changes); previously, it was unset.)

```
if hasattr(mod, '__path__') and getattr(mod, '__file__', None) is None:
    print("It's a namespace package.")
```

In contrast, modules that aren't packages don't have a `__path__`, and packages that aren't namespace packages have `__file__` set to the location of their `__init__.py`.

Comment: In my code, both namespace and regular modules have a `__path__`, is there a reason for checking the `__path__` attribute exists?

Comment: @NathanaelFarley: Packages have a `__path__`, but non-package modules don't. The `__path__` check is there to distinguish namespace packages from built-in modules like `sys`, which also don't have a `__file__`.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Python 3.8 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec.origin), `__file__` is:

> Name of the place from which the module is loaded, e.g. “builtin” for built-in modules and the filename for modules loaded from source. Normally “origin” should be set, but it may be None (the default) which indicates it is unspecified (e.g. for namespace packages).

Also, the correct answer should be:

```py
is_namespace = (
    lambda module: hasattr(module, "__path__")
    and getattr(module, "__file__", None) is None
)
```

Comment: Oh crud, you're right - [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#specification) says a namespace package "Does not have a `__file__` attribute", but it looks like that got changed to `__file__=None` at some point.

Comment: Any reason for using `lambda` over  `def`?

Comment: Just a matter of taste. Here I wanted minimal and inline stuff.